# What does running a coroutine or rx observable on the main thread accomplish

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, you specify the type of thread that you want your code to run on by indicating what dispatcher to use (IO, Main, etc). In a similar way, with rxJava, you can also indicate what thread to run on. However with rxJava, you generally will run something on an IO thread to do the background work, then switch to the main thread (which is the UI thread) to display stuff.

But I have seen a lot of code where a coroutine uses only the main thread. It doesn't switch from an IO thread to the main thread. I haven't seen this done in rxJava, although I'm sure it exists.

But my question is why would you do this? If you're only going to use the main thread, why even bother with using a coroutine or rxJava at all? Does not running a coroutine on the main thread the same thing as running it on the main thread without a coroutine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have seen a lot of code where a coroutine uses only the main thread.

Very often, a coroutine will invoke code that is run on another thread like `Dispatchers.IO`, but it generally happens "under the hood". For example, consider the following code from [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines):

```
suspend fun fetchDocs() {
    val result = get("https://developer.android.com")
    show(result)
}
```

on first glance, it might look like this coroutine does not switch thread. But when you look at the implementation of `get()` you can see that it does indeed switch thread:

```
suspend fun get(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /* ... */ }
```

If you dive deeper into the code you have seen, you will virtually always find a switch to a worker thread pool such as `Dispatchers.IO` (otherwise there is no point in using coroutines like you point out).

> But my question is why would you do this?

The reason most coroutine builders such as [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) default to using `Dispatchers.Main` is because then you don't have to worry about thread safety for your "top level code". The general pattern is "run all coroutines on `Dispathers.Main`, but switch to e.g. `Dispathers.IO` under the hood when necessary to not block the `Main` thread."

That way you can have simple code. In the example above, the `show(result)` method does not need to be thread safe, because it will only be used from the `Main` thread.

There is no problem with running code on the Main thread as long as the code does not block the main thread, which generally means "does not perform disk or network IO".